# Gradient calculation for Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, gradient-flows

I have the following:

$$b^T a^{-1} b$$ what is the gradient wrt to $a$. $a$ is matrix and $b$ is vector. Basically I should take the derivative with respect to $a$. Is it correct that it equals to:

$$-ba^{-2}b^T$$ or there is a better way to represent? If someone give me a step by step instruction I would appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:a\in M_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow b^Ta^{-1}b$. The derivative is: $Df_a:H\in M_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow -b^Ta^{-1}Ha^{-1}b=trace(-a^{-1}bb^Ta^{-1}H)$ and the gradient is $\nabla f(a)=-(a^{-1})^Tbb^T(a^{-1})^T$.

Comment: Well I am bit confused here because I have a little different result $\frac{\partial b^T a^{-1}b}{\partial a} =\frac{\partial Tr(a^{-1}bb^T)}{\partial a}=-a^{-1}bb^Ta^{-1}$

Comment: Yes Alexander, you find the transpose. A standard definition of the gradient is: for every $H\in M_n(\mathbb{R}),(\nabla f(a),H)=Df_a(H)$ with the scalar product $(U,V)=trace(U^TV)$. Yet you may choose another definition.

Comment: @ Alexander Vigodner, I reread your post. How do you find your last equality ?

Comment: I am using definition of well known http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf. And in a case $a$  is not symmetric I don't think  we have to get tthe different results. What I get is the matrix each element of those $z_{ij}$ is the derivative with respect $a_{ij}$. I am affraid your result might be interpreted not correctly.

Comment: $\frac {\partial Tr(X^{-1}A}{\partial X}=-X^{-1}AX^{-1}$

Comment: Alexander, it is the formula (16) of your reference. It is the derivative; yet the gradient is the transpose of the derivative. For instance let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$; then the derivative $Df_a$ is a $1\times n$ matrix and the gradient is a vector $n\times 1$. Alexander, you are right; the OP asked for a derivative !

Comment: The difference I think that in my notation $dy =Adx$ . In you notation $dy=A^Tdx$ where $A$ is the gradient ( derivative)

Comment: But the guy asked about the derivative :).

Comment: Actually it seems for me I was wrong  Minka wrote "the partials with respect to the denominator are laid out according to the transpose of $X$". So your matrix is correct even in my defintions.